# Is normalization consistent with Schrodinger's Equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, superposition, linear-systems

Schrodinger's Equation does not set a limit on the size of wave functions but to normalize a wave function a limit must be set.  How is this consistent physically and mathematically with Schrodinger's Equation.

Comment: The title of this question is very confusing: Normalization of wave functions has absolutely nothing to do with [renormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization). Renormalization can not be applied to wave functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Schrodinger's equation is homogeneous -- so if $\phi_1,\phi_2,\cdots,\phi_n$ are solutions, $c_1\phi_1 + c_2\phi_2  + \cdots +c_n\phi_n$ is a solution.

More importantly, if $\phi$ is a solution, $A\phi$ is a solution as well. If $A$ is the normalization constant, we see that both non-normalized and normalized versions are valid solutions of Schrodinger's equation, making it consistent.

Comment: Also the normalization is conserved by Schrodinger's equation, so once you normalize the wavefunction it stays normalized (of course I'm ignoring projective measurements, which are not described by the Schrodinger equation).

Answer (score 0):

MATHEMATICALLY, if a function $\phi$ is a solution of the SE:
$$
H\phi=E\phi
$$
then $c\phi$ (c is a constant) is also a solution of it due to its linearity.

PHYSICALLY, however, we cannot choose any mathematical solution of the above SE equation to be the physical solution. Remember that we are working with Physics, not Mathematics. In Quantum Mechanics, wave function is probability amplitude and wave function squared is probability density. It's clear that we can find a particle in whole space with a probability of 1; or,in other work, we will definitely find out the particle in whole space. So, we must choose the constant $c$ so that the integral of the wave function squared over whole space must be 1 (normalization condition). The normalized solutions of the SE equation are really physical solutions, or wave functions.